# high voltage isolated dc/dc converter watt selection problem

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, flyback, texas-instruments

I am a beginner circuit developer.

I used a TI WEBENCH POWER DESIGNER, to make all-in-one battery management system power design.

POWER DESIGNER made a recommendation like the picture.

Specifically,

Input : 15V ~ 80V

Output : 5V 1.5A

In the program, there is no maximum current input value, so it was ignored.

The maximum current value of the battery will be around 30A.

But in the circuit design, Rvin power value is 100mW, Rvsd is 125mW

[image]
It is questionable whether Rvin, Rvsd can withstand when a maximum current of about 30A flows.

The rest of the resistors were likewise chosen with a somewhat lower wattage.

Is the wattage selection method different in this circuit?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What are your expectations from having an input power or current value to fill in?

Comment: why would 30A flow? Just because your battery *can* supply that much current, doesn't mean that's actually what flows!

Comment: Is it okay to think that the power of Rvin doesn't have to be considered high since the U1 IC only properly draws and receives the current it needs?

Comment: (~80V) / 133 = ~0.6A 
I thought that a certain amount of current would flow

Comment: What do you think the purpose of M2 is?

Comment: The datasheet states that this is the start up part. 
maybe it's the ic drive part